# Vuejs2 cancel http requests on route navigate

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Am trying to cancel older uncomplete http requests when a user navigates away (destroyed) life cycle

currently i have a method

```
methods:{
   getdata(){
     this.$http.get("users").then((res)=>{

          ///do stuff with returned data
     })
   }
}
```

NOw how do i cancel the above http request if it isnt complete

SO something like this in the destroyed life cycle

```
destroyed(){
  //here cancel above http request
}
```

How do i go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
let ongoingRequest
export default {
    beforeDestroy() {
        ongoingRequest.abort()
    },
    methods: {
        getdata() {
            this.$http.get("users", {
                before(request) {
                    ongoingRequest = request
                }
            }).then((res) => {
                ///do stuff with returned data
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I found an issue talking about that [here](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/issues/622).

Comment: Thanks i see this does it